# What is the best way to match optional whole words with python regex

Tags: python, regex

I use regualr expressions frequently, but often in the same similar ways. I sometimes run across this scenario where I'd like to capture strings with optional whole words in them. I've come up with the method below but I suspect there's a better way, just not sure what it is? An example is a string like this:

`For the purposes of this order, the sum of $5,476,958.00 is the estimated total costs of the initial unit well covered hereby as dry hole and for the purposes of this order, the sum of $12,948,821.00 is the estimated total costs of such initial unit well as a producing well`

My goal is to capture both portions of the string beginning with the dollar sign `$` and ending with either word `dry` or `prod`. In the example the whole word is `producing`, but sometimes it's a variation of the word such as `production`, so `prod` is fine. The captured results should be:

`['$5,476,958.00 is the estimated total costs of the initial unit well covered hereby as dry', '$12,948,821.00 is the estimated total costs of such initial unit well as a prod']`

which I get with this not so elegant expression:
`[val[0] for val in re.findall('(\$[0-9,\.]+[a-z ,]+total cost.*?(dry|prod)+)', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]`

Is there a better, more correct, way to accomplish it than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = "For the purposes of this order, the sum of $5,476,958.00 is the estimated total costs of the initial unit well covered hereby as dry hole and for the purposes of this order, the sum of $12,948,821.00 is the estimated total costs of such initial unit well as a producing well"
matches = re.findall(r'\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?.*?\b(?:dry|prod)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['$5,476,958.00 is the estimated total costs of the initial unit well covered hereby as dry',
 '$12,948,821.00 is the estimated total costs of such initial unit well as a prod']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern being used:

- `\$` match currency symbol `$`
- `\d{1,3}` match 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` followed by optional thousands terms
- `(?:\.\d+)?` followed by optional decimal component
- `.*?` match all content until reaching the nearest
- `\b(?:dry|prod)` match `dry` or `prod` as a substring

Comment: I knew I was close but `\b(?:dry|prod)` was the missing piece, thanks Tim